# How do i convert everything on stage to a movie clip using as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I want to be able to convert everything I have added on stage to a MovieClip through ActionScript.

So lets say I now have:

```
stage.addChild(pic1);
stage.addChild(pic2);
```

where `pic1` and`pic2` are instances of a MovieClip I have,
now after this I want to make both of these together into a MovieClip through code and be able to access that MovieClip object.

Comment: as in just reparenting pic1 and pic2 ? That should be something as simple as `var both:Sprite = addChild(new Sprite()) as Sprite;both.addChild(pic1);both.addChild(pic2);`

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a quick way to re-parent *everything* on the stage whether you know the instance names or not, you'll have to loop through all the children of the stage.

```
var myMovieClip:MovieClip = new MovieClip(); // the MovieClip to contain your children
var l:int = stage.numChildren; // how many things are on the stage
for (var i:int = 0; i<l; i++){ // loop through all of them
     myMovieClip.addChild(stage.getChildAt(0)); //removes the bottom DisplayObject from the stage and adds it to your container
}
addChild(myMovieClip); //adds the complete MovieClip back to the stage;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var newMC:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
newMC.addChild(pic1);
newMC.addChild(pic2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Container which allows interactivity eg. click detection

```
var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
sprite.addChild(pic1);
sprite.addChild(pic2);
```

As per crooksy88 answer above, though I am not sure what the benefits would be to use a MovieClip in this scenario

Comment: This first code fragment will give you `ArgumentError`, since you cannot directly instantiate `DisplayObjectContainer`.

Comment: Thanks, I have removed that example, I have done this before, I think it was Flex.

Answer (score 0):

`Stage` and `MovieClip` both inherit from `DisplayObjectContainer`, which defines the method [`addChild()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#addChild%28%29).

This means that you can easily create a `MovieClip` and add that to the stage:

```
var container:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
stage.addChild(container);
```

And then add other DisplayObjects into that:

```
container.addChild(pic1);
container.addChild(pic2);
```

Manipulating position, scale, rotation and other similar properties will affect the contents of the container.